# ContourPlot to decide geometric shape

Tags: plotting

I'm supposed to use ContourPlot to decide - for different values of `a` - whether the following curve:

```
(3a^2-1)(x^2+y^2)-2*x*y+4a(x+y)-a2^2=0
```

is (A) an ellipse, (B) a hyperbola, (C) a parabola, (D) a line, (E) two intersecting lines, (F) two parallel lines, (G) a point, (H) an empty range.

Values for a:
$$
a<\sqrt(2/3)\\
a = -\sqrt(2/3)\\
-\sqrt(2/3) < a < 0\\
a=0\\
0<a<\sqrt(2/3)\\
a=<\sqrt(2/3)\\
a>\sqrt(2/3)$$

I thought this would work:

```
a='different values'

ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 = 0,
  {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

..but it just returns a box filled in with blue.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=` should be `==` inside `ContourPlot`/

Answer (score 1):

You need to give "a" a value:

```
Do[eq = (3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 ; 
 ContourPlot[eq == 0, {x, - 10^2, 10^2}, {y, - 10^2, 10^2}, 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["a= ``", a]] // 
  Print, {a, {Sqrt[2/3] - 0.1, -Sqrt[2/3], -0.5, 0, 0.5, Sqrt[2/3], 
   Sqrt[2/3] + 0.001}}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check the formula and the numerical values you give? Anyway, below I provide a way to plot what you have given. A simple fix is the following:

Check the numerical value:

```
Sqrt[2]/3 // N
```

> 0.471405

First one:

```
With[{a = 0.35}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: first pic]

Second:

```
With[{a = -(Sqrt[2]/3)}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: second]

Third:

```
With[{a = -0.35}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: third]

Fourth:

```
With[{a = 0}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: fourth]

Fifth:

```
With[{a = 0.45}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: fifth]

Sixth:

```
With[{a = Sqrt[2]/3}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: six]

Final:

```
With[{a = 0.95}, 
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 2 a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: final]

Comment: Thank you!! And you were right, the numerical values were slightly off. Can't edit the post right now.

Comment: glad i was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

- 

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2*x*y + 4 a (x + y) - a^2 == 
   0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, -1,1}]
```

[image]

*

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2*x*y + 4 a (x + y) - 
   a^2, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> {Blue, None}], {a, -1, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

- Use `ContourPlot3D`.

```
h = 0.8; 
ContourPlot3D[{(3 a^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2*x*y + 
    4 a (x + y) - a^2 == 0, a == h}, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 
  100}, {a, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]